# Expected value of product of mixed random variables and Variance of their sum

Tags: probability

Suppose $X$~$N(0,1)$. Suppose $Y=b$ when $X \ge 0$ and $Y=a$ when $X<0$ when $a,b$ are any constants. Am I doing the expected value correct for E(XY)?

$E(XY) = .5E(XY|Y=a) + .5E(XY|Y=b) = \frac{-.5a}{\sqrt{2\pi}}+\frac{.5b}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$

Also, I am looking at the variance of their sum is this correct?

$VAR(X+Y)=E(X^2)+E(Y^2)+2E(XY)-(E(X+Y))^2 =1+\frac{a^2+b^2}{2}+\frac{b-a}{\sqrt{2\pi}}-\frac{(a+b)^2}{4}$.

Finally, an answer I appreciate from you is how I could prove that the above variance is greater than or equal to $0$.  I know it must be by definition but I would like to see it just using the value that is there.  It seems like if $a>b$ then the last two terms might be greater than the first two.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems right to me. The last expression is positive :

$$\frac{a^2+b^2}{2}-\frac{(a+b)^2}{4}=\frac{a^2-2ab+b^2}{4}=\left(\frac{b-a}{2}\right)^2$$

$$V(X+Y)=1+\left(\frac{b-a}{2}\right)^2+\frac{b-a}{\sqrt{2\pi}}=P(b-a)$$

with $P(X)=\frac{1}{4}X^2+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}X+1$

$\Delta(P )=\frac{1}{2\pi}-1<0$ Hence $P(X)$ has no real roots and is always positive.

Comment: good answer thanks.